# Php Mysql query not working when adding AND parameter with >=

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get my php script to output the name of a row in my mysql database.  I know the issue is with the long >= '$Slong'.  The long value in the datase is a float.  The Slong value is set to 1.11 and there is a row that has the long value at 1.21.

I believe this is where the problem lies:

```
$Slong = $long - 0.01;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM locations WHERE age < '$age' AND aTime = 'Morning' AND long >= '$Slong'");
```

Comment: stop using deprecated version `mysql_*`. turn to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements

Comment: @Anant can you point me in the place to find the information on this please?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: I am not getting a error @mitkosoft it just isn't outputting anything

Comment: you can go for php.net manuals regarding this

Comment: `long` is reserved word, so either put backticks around it or change the name of the column

Comment: Ok thank you I'll check it out @Anant.  I still would like to learn from my question though.

Comment: Ok @mitkosoft what is a backtick?  is it this \

Comment: Nope. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands

Comment: So like this ` long `? but without spaces

Comment: Yes, check and let us know..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118604/discussion-between-max-and-mitkosoft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Long` is reserved keyword, so use backticks around:

```
$Slong = $long - 0.01;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM locations WHERE age < '$age' AND aTime = 'Morning' AND `long` >= '$Slong'");
```

Answer (score 0):

`long` is keyword in sql. You should use back tick character(`).

For back tick, refer https://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows

Also instead of using direct substitution values, you could use below methods to avoid sql injection.

You basically have two options to achieve this:

Using PDO (for any supported database driver):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array('name' => $name));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Using MySQLi (for MySQL):

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Please refer [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)